# How to get android AccountManager and ASP.NET WebAPI with default google authentication to work together?

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, google-oauth, google-openid

I have an MVC 5 WebAPI project using google external authentication (the default one meaning i only uncommented app.Usegoogle... in the Startup class).

From my android app, I want to authenticate to my webapi without prompting the user to sign in to google, just by choosing an account from his existing accounts.

I could call the GetExternalLogin method on my WebAPI and then have it redirect me to google, have the user sign in in a webview and let the OWIN  middle wear do its thing. But I want to use the existing accounts on the device.

Using AccountManager.getAuthToken I can directly get an access token. But how can I use this to authenticate using the same GetExternalLogin method?

Another option would be to create a new method on my APIController to receive the access token that is sent from my android app, then have it make a call to a google api to get his identity and then somehow sign the user in using the default Usermanager?